# where can i find the source code for /dev/random driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to see how /dev/random creates random numbers. I understand that it uses entropy made from interrupts but I'd still like to see the source and how it works.

Thanks

Comment: So easy to google I feel dirty for even answering.

Comment: Not so. I did google stuff like "/dev/random" "/dev/random source" "/dev/random source c". I also did "linux /dev/random source" and other variations. But thanks for answering it for me anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://lxr.linux.no/linux/drivers/char/random.c

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [random.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/char/random.c) in the drivers section of *THE* [linux-kernel](/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) source code, a project of Linus Torvalds on GitHub.